# I can't loop over an array from Vuex

Tags: arrays, vue.js, foreach, vuex

I am developing this small web page to store recipes using Vue, Vuex, and Firebase.

I have a component where I want to display a sort of tag cloud for later filtering. The problem is that after storing the array in the component I can not access the array itself to perform actions over it.
I know the data is there because I display a list of the recipes with a v-for, but I cannot do a `for` or `forEach`.

I have here the code :

```
methods: {
    getRecipes() {
      this.recipes = this.$store.getters.allRecipes;
    },

    getTags() {
      console.log(this.recipes);  // ==> Here the recipes show OK

      this.recipes.forEach((recipe) => {
        console.log(recipe); // ==> It never logs here
      });

      // ==> I have also done it with the long way, and doesn't log

      // for (let i = 0; i < this.recipes.length; i++) {
      //   const element = this.recipes[i];
      //   console.log(element);
      // }
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("clearStore");
    this.$store.dispatch("getRecipes").then(this.getRecipes(), this.getTags());
  }
```

I also tried bringing in the data with a computed property and it displayed the list ok (and I believe it's the proper way of doing it) but I still couldn't iterate over the array.

Trying to log `this.recipes` to the console returns the observer object Vue creates, which is expected, but in the Vue DevTools, it shows an array as it should.
In the console:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}
4: {…}
5: {…}
6: {…}
7: {…}
8: {…}
9: {…}
length: 10
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(10), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

When logging the `this.recipes.length` it shows `0`

For shits and giggles, I have tried with the data locally in the component and it works.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your `getRecipes` action (not the method), but the fetch has not necessarily completed when you access the getter if the action is constructed incorrectly.  The fact that it does work when using a computed shows that the data does come in later, because the computed then adjusts, and then you see it.

I recommend using a computed for the component's `getRecipes` and `getTags` methods and then it won't matter, but if you want this pattern instead, change your `getRecipes` action:

```js
actions: {
  async getRecipes() {
    const response = await axios.get(...);
    // set data
    return response.data; 
  }
}
```

Returning the fetch promise would work too if you didn't want to use `async/await`:

```js
actions: {
  getRecipes() {
    return axios.get(...).then(response => {
      // set data
      return response.data;
    });
  }
}
```